# PHP drop down menu value from database

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I have an Oracle database. In my database I have a table called "DRIVER". I created 3 collumns inside the table called ID,CAR and PERSON.
I need to create a drop down menu where I will be able to choose one from all the cars that are in the column "CAR". When I choose a car from drop down menu, automatically in the textbox bellow will be written a name of the person that owns the car.

Example:
Let's choose a car in the 3rd position from drop down menu. Automatically when I choose the 3rd car the textbox bellow will write name of the person with an ID = 3.

I only made a drop down menu and an empty textbox. I don't have a clue what to do next. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner and I had a help even with this part of the code.

```
<?php
  $ora_sql2 = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DRIVER.ID,DRIVER.CAR,DRIVER.PERSON FROM DRIVER');
  oci_execute($ora_sql2, OCI_DEFAULT);
?>

<form method="post" action="insert.php">
  <table width="319" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td>
      <select name="drop_menu" id="drop_menu">
      <?php 
            while(oci_fetch($ora_sql2))
        { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo oci_result($ora_sql2, 'ID')?>"><?php echo oci_result($ora_sql2, 'CAR')?></option>
        <?php   
        }?>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <label for="textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript for that. You can listen to the 'change' event of the select box and if fired, assign the text box.

The first example on http://api.jquery.com/change/ is the answer of your question.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement that script into my code but I encountered 2 problems. 1) I coulnd't find a way to run the script as a value of the textbox. I can only run the script outside of the textbox in an empty space.    2) In that link you provided the example does only copy of the value from the drop down menu and then write it somewhere. I get it. But I tried it to work with my database and I couldn't figure how to make it write an person of the car. I tried all the stupid things like `str += <?php echo oci_result($ora_sql2, 'PERSON')?>;` but ofcourse it wouldn't work :)